# Cannot access dynamically created element in Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

In my app using Angular 4, I am trying to dynamically create an element and get its position on button click (Both actions happen in one button click). However, since the element is not created when accessing its position, the element returns null.

This is the method executed on click:

```
  addNodeWithEdge(node){
    this.addNewNode();    
    this.currentNode = this.nodeList.length-1;
    var elementGenerated = document.getElementById(this.currentNode); //returns null
    var to = this.getCentreOfElement(elementGenerated);
  }

  addNewNode() {
    let newNode = new SntNode("", []);
    this.nodeList.push(newNode);
  }

  getCentreOfElement(el) {
    var xPos = el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth/2;
    var yPos = el.offsetTop - el.offsetHeight/2;
    return {
      x: xPos,
      y: yPos
    };
  }
```

And on the view:

```
<a (click)="addNewNode()"></a>

<ng-container *ngFor="let node of nodeList; index as n">
    <div class="node-block" id={{n}}>
         <div class="node-cmp" (click)="onSelectNode(n)">
              <a class="a-tag-circle">{{node.name}}</a>
         </div>
         <div class="node-opts"></div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

A node is added to `nodeList` when the `addNewNode()` is triggered. In the view, all nodes in the `nodeList` are added to the view in a for loop (`*ngFor`). This addition to the view is not executed until the function `addNewNodeWithEdge()` is fully executed. Since `document.getElementById` is executed before the view is refreshed, it returns null.

How do I solve this? Should I refresh the component after creating the element? If so how can I refresh component in Angular? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does `this.addNewNode()` do (and return)?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited to add method functionality now.

Comment: `document.getElementById` can only find elements that are added to the document. I don't see you adding a node to the document.

Comment: @FelixKling A node is added to `nodeList` when the `addNewNode()` is triggered. In the view, all nodes in the nodeList are added to the view in a for loop (`*ngFor`). This addition to the view is not executed until the function `addNewNodeWithEdge()` is fully executed. Since `document.getElementById` is executed before the view is refreshed, it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Here, in below given line you need to provide ID of element instead of index.

```
var elementGenerated = document.getElementById(this.secondNode); //returns null
```

Comment: I have set the array index as the id of the element :)

Comment: share logic of  `this.addNewNode()` function